# Detecting No Squint Extension Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon

QUESTION Is there a way to detect if a visitor is using the NoSquint extension for Firefox?

BACKGROUND:
I have a games site where all the game web apps scale to fit the window, which enables the user to determine how big the app appears. NoSquint provides a similar feature to enlarge sites to make them easier to read. But this conflicts with our built-in autoscale feature and causes the page to become too large to fit the window. If the user understood what is happening, the user could tell NoSquint not to scale a particular website. Unfortunately, people don't understand what is going on and it results in support emails. If I can detect the existence of the extension, I can deactivate our autoscaler.